# start activity inside fragment without button click. Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

How do i start an activity inside fragment without button click?
I want to directly start a activity inside fragment without clicking the button.
I have searched for answers but every answer is related to button click.
Please help. I am new to android.

Comment: What do you mean start an activity inside fragment? It isnt possible. A fragment can be started in activity not the other way around. Look on youtube for videos about fragment and activity comparision by slidenerd or TheNewBoston.

Comment: means not a clere way to do this

Comment: But if you need to call activity from fragment then it doesn't mean. Mean when you load your fragment in just a moment your activity will be started if  you will call in `oncreateView()` method. So its better to call from activity.

Comment: @DigveshPatel If you could tell what you are trying to do then we can help you better with answer or alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

override `oncreateView()` method and in that

```
Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),yourActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me clear about Activity & Fragment. Activity is basic android component which can hold many Fragment. Fragment can not hold any Activity. For example : `MyActivity` is an activity which may hold `MyFragment1` & `MyFragment2`. Now you can go from Fragment to another activity not `MyActivity` because `MyActivity` is already running & holding fragments. If you want to go `MyActivity2` from fragment then write simple activity starting code. I am giving it bellow.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),MyActivity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

You can write it `onCreateView` of fragment.